# Автоматизация создания пользователя Openvpn

Tags: linux, bash, openvpn

Прошу помочь со скриптом создания пользователя openvpn на bash. Заранее спасибо.

```
#!/bin/sh
$openvpn-name = somename;
$openvpn-passwd = 4oLolo;

cd /openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/;
. ./vars;
./build-key-pkcs12 $openvpn-name;
```

На параметры ниже(: ) ответ просто enter

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [US]: 
State or Province Name (full name) [CA]:
Locality Name (eg, city) [SanFrancisco]:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Fort-Funston]:
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) [somename]:
Name [changeme]:
Email Address [mail@host.domain]:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []: 
An optional company name []:
```

На эти параметры ответ :y

```
Certificate is to be certified until May 11 08:32:35 2030 GMT (3650 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]: y
1 out of 1 certificate requests certified, commit? [y/n] y
Data Base Updated
```

Не уверен, что с паролем получится. В идеале, чтобы он генерировался произвольно и сохранялся отдельно в файле.

```
Enter Export Password: $openvpn-passwd
Verifying - Enter Export Password: $openvpn-passwd
```

Ключ создан, теперь его необходимо скопировать из /openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys в /home/keys

```
cp  /openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/$openvpn-name.p12 /home/keys;
chmod -R 755 /home/keys
```

Answer (score 0):

```
openvpnname=somename

mkdir -p keys
cp /openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.* keys/

openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout keys/$openvpnname.key\
        -out keys/$openvpnname.csr \
        -subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Global Security/OU=IT Department/CN=$openvpnname"

openssl x509 -req -days 360 -in keys/$openvpnname.csr \
        -CA keys/ca.crt -CAkey keys/ca.key\
        -CAcreateserial -out keys/$openvpnname.crt

dd if=/dev/urandom count=6 bs=1 | base64 > keys/$openvpnname.password

openssl rsa -aes256 -in keys/$openvpnname.key -out keys/$openvpnname.key \
        -passout file:keys/$openvpnname.password
```

Ключи можно сделать через `openssl`.  Если заполнить `-subj` то он ничего спрашивать не будет. Ключ сохранится без пароля. Новый случайный пароль делаем через urandom и сохраняем в файл. Последняя команда поменяет пароль на ключе.

Ах, да. Конвертнуть в p12

```
cp keys/$openvpnname.password keys/$openvpnname.p12.password
openssl pkcs12 -export -in keys/$openvpnname.crt -inkey keys/$openvpnname.key \
        -out keys/$openvpnname.p12 \
        -passin file:keys/$openvpnname.password \
        -passout file:keys/$openvpnname.p12.password
```